# How to add additional views to a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a wordpress plugin that is working and its url looks like this:

http://example.com/resources

What I am looking to do is add some more views into the plugin code so that I can support urls like this:

http://example.com/resources/anotherview

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve or an example of your current code?

Comment: Sure thing martin.....
I have a list of resources (documents) that shows up at the example.com/resources url.  I would like to be able to have additional views that would allow a user to view only object of a certain tag type.  So example.com/resources/tags/foo would show a list of resources that have the tag of foo.  Resources are a custom post type in this case and I am trying to keep the listing to just these custom post type.  I hope that helps to describe the issue better.

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is create a custom taxonomy that is slugged /resources, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a switch and also grab the url then display what you want via this.

```
//demo url
    $url = 'http://www.1st.com/folder/folder2/file.php';
    $brakeurl = explode('/', $url);
    $url_name[sizeof($brakeurl)-1];
    //test url to see what folder we get
    //echo $url_name;

        switch ($url_name){
        case 'folder name':
            $content = '';
            break;
        case 'othername':
            $content = '';
            break;
       default:
        echo "no folder so lets do something.";
        break;


    }
```